# Electron jQuery without require on html

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, electron, angular-cli

I'm developing an angular webapp which works very well on browser. When i wanted to put it on Electron BrowserWindow, i encountered a problem with 3rd party libraries integration such as jQuery which is required by bootstrap.

The next cheat at the end of site `index` works on electron, but not on browser :

`<script> window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); </script>`

However including jQuery on .angular-cli.json, works on browser, but not on electron.
```

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

```

Any help please :)

Comment: what about include in your index.html <script href="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" and not in your angular-cli.json?

Comment: I don't include it in index, because it's already bundled and included by webpack build